# emberjs - reusing views/components that need to load data

Tags: ember.js

I am very new to ember.

how do i create a component/view that has to load data, for ex if i need a search box on multiple page (with some extra properties passed in), which hits the database and gets results. every documentation i read says the model has to be passed in to the view. however i do not want to copy the code which loads search results from the backend on every page.

ideally what i want to do
{{view myseachbox... extrafilter="yyy"}}

is setting the controllerBinding to say MySearchController where the functionality of fetching data will be implemented the way to go?

any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Ember Data?

Comment: yes. so i have now implemented it with adding a controllerBinding=SearchBoxController and doing all data fetches inside that.